# How do I find the most frequently occurring element in a column based on a value in another column in Excel?

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

Assume I have this table:

[image: Spreadsheet Data]

As you can see, ***`4`*** is the most frequently occurring value corresponding to `100` and ***`6`*** is the most frequently occurring value corresponding to `200`.

How can I express that in a function? A simple `MATCH`-`INDEX` function returns only the first element in column B corresponding to the value I use from column A.

How can I get the most frequent one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an array formula finalized with ctrl+shift+enter,

```
=MODE.SNGL(IF(A$1:A$13=100, B$1:B$13))
```

[image]

Comment: It worked!  But what about this case: assume I have on column `B` 4 results that share the same frequency. Like for `100` to have for example {2, 2, 4, 4}. They both show up the same amount of times in column B. How can I pick the just the smallest value (`2` in this case)?

Comment: If there are two values matching the highest frequency, MODE.SNGL will return the first one found. {2, 2, 4, 4} will return 2 but {4, 4, 2, 2} will return 4. However, `=MIN(MODE.MULT(IF(A$1:A$15=E6, B$1:B$15)))` will return 2 for both {2, 2, 4, 4} and {4, 4, 2, 2} since the minimum value is 2.

Comment: I found a small issue with this. If you have one or two (maybe n, if they are all different) elements in column B, not sharing the same value, for example, if for `100` you have only `1` or `{1, 2}` or `{1,2,3...n}` the function will return nothing. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I ended up writing something like `IFERROR(MIN(MODE.MULT(IF(A:A=E1,C:C,""))),INDEX(C:C, MATCH(E1, A:A,0)))`, but then again, it only returns the first element and not the smallest one.